# Initialize JXDatePicker with custom date

Tags: java, swingx

I want to initialize a JXDatepicker with a custom date. At the moment I´m trying this:

```
    Date date1= new Date(2006-01-01);    
    Date date2 = new Date();
    jGeburtVon.setDate(date1);
    jGeburtBis.setDate(date2);`
```

Edited: this is the real code from the program ; it does compile and run and you´re right of course, new Date() initializes to today, not 01.01.1970. In this code though, date1 initializes to 01.01.1970.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Show us your real code. And new Date() returns the current date/time, not 01.01.1970. And the Date constructor taking a string as argument is deprecated. You should not use it. Read the javadoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the JXDatePicker method you're looking for is `setDate(Date date)`
Javadoc for the JXDatePicker can be found [here](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXDatePicker.html#setDate%28java.util.Date%29).

Answer (score 1):

This way date1 is created not with a String but with a long: 2006-01-01 = 2006 - 1 - 1 = 2004, which is 2004 milliseconds after 1970-01-01_00:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It has to look like this:

```
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
 Date date1 = df.parse("01.01.2006");
```

Reading the javadocs does help sometimes :)
Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SimpleDateFormat`, you can create a `Date` object from your `String`. Using that object and `DateTimePicker`'s `setDate` method you can assign the date to your object. Hope that helps.

> *Original text answer in spanish*
>   <sub><sub>utilizando el SimpleDateFormat, podes crear un objeto date a partir de tu String, luego usando ese objeto y mediante mensaje setDate del DateTimePicker,podes asignar la fecha a tu objeto.Espero te sirva.</sub></sub>

```
    DateTimePicker dateChooser = new DateTimePicker();        
    Date date = new Date();
    Date fecha= new Date();
    try {
        fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:S").parse("2016-02-15 :00:00:00");
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    date.setTime(fecha.getTime());
    dateChooser.setFormats("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    dateChooser.setTimeFormat( DateFormat.getTimeInstance( DateFormat.MEDIUM ) );
    dateChooser.setDate(date);
```